# Актуален ли firebase в 2020?

Tags: android, firebase

Актуален ли firebase в 2020 (в моём случае для android) или всё же лучше использовать room?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это совершенно разные вещи, их нельзя сравнивать.

**FirebaseDatabase** - это **облачное** NoSql хранилище данных. Используется когда нет возможности поднимать собственный сервер с хранением данных на нём. Лично моё мнение - использовать стоит только в самом крайнем случае, т.к. вещь мало того что неудобная, обрезанная, требующая большого опыта так ещё и платная на нетестовых объёмах.

**Room** же - это библиотека-обёртка на SqLite СУБД, используемая для хранения **локальных** данных на девайсе. Ни в коем случае не может быть заменой для облачного хранения данных.